# .NET threading model

Tags: .net, multithreading

When we create a thread in .NET via `ThreadPool` or `Task.Run` or a `Thread` object, is that thread mapped to a single Windows thread or it could be mapped to multiple ones? In other words, what's the [Threading Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing)#Models) of .Net CLR?
Can somebody please shed a light here?

**PS**: Similar question about `JVM` has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427398/java-threads-vs-os-threads), but I couldn't find similar one for `.NET`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, each managed thread is mapped to a single OS thread. However, by using CLR hosting APIs, you can migrate managed threads to different native OS threads.

From [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2):

> An operating-system ThreadId has no fixed relationship to a managed
>   thread, because an unmanaged host can control the relationship between
>   managed and unmanaged threads. Specifically, a sophisticated host can
>   use the CLR Hosting API to schedule many managed threads against the
>   same operating system thread, or to move a managed thread between
>   different operating system threads.

However, you can ask CLR to not move your managed thread to another OS thread by calling [Thread.BeginThreadAffinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.beginthreadaffinity?view=netframework-4.7.2).

This means .NET threading model is N:M.

Comment: So it means N:M model.

Comment: That's correct. I've edited my answer to include this.